# What is the difference between CPU and Microprocessor?

Tags: cpu, terminology

What is the difference between CPU and Microprocessor?

Comment: CPU vs. MCU   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller

Comment: @Aki: An MCU is a different thing entirely.

Answer (score 15):

A microprocessor is essentially a processor that happens to be on a chip (or a small number of chips), as opposed to one made from a large number of individual components.

As foo says, properly CPU refers to the *main* processor(s) of a system, though most of the time we call any processor that is typically used in this way a CPU. For example, we might refer to the Z80 processor in a Sega Mega Drive/Genesis as a CPU even though it actually serves as an auxiliary to the main processor, which is a more powerful Motorola 68k. (I believe the Z80 is often used to control the music and sound effects, though there is no reason why it would *have* to be used at all in a particular game.)

For an example of a CPU that is not a microprocessor, take a look at [this 4-bit CPU](http://www.galacticelectronics.com/Simple4BitCPU.HTML):

[image]

Comment: +1 nailed the main differentiation in the first paragraph.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, and for the 4-bit-CPU counter-example

Answer (score 2):

In everyday use: nothing, just the name.

If you want to be correct: a CPU is the "main" microprocessor, if you have several combined - the one that controls the others. Hence, **Central** Processing Unit.

Answer (score 1):

A CPU ("central processing unit") is the core of a computer or a microprocesso, typically containing a "arithmetic/logical unit (ALU)" that does the computational work, an instruction fetcher, decoder and executer.

A microprocessor is a packaged electronic component containing a CPU, I/O, and memory access circuits.