# What does Microprocessor looks like?

Tags: cpu

I googled [microprocessor](https://www.google.com.ph/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicshub.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F06%2FMicroprocessor1.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicshub.org%2Fmicroprocessors%2F&docid=b5WbQu4ofu5lEM&tbnid=G3tdv7VKvbZPOM%3A&w=1500&h=1323&bih=643&biw=1366&ved=0ahUKEwiFtZLDt_3OAhWEG5QKHVKsCm0QMwgzKAIwAg&iact=mrc&uact=8) and [CPU](https://www.google.com.ph/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easy-computer-tech.com%2Fimages%2FCPU.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easy-computer-tech.com%2Fcpu.html&docid=6C7A6L_axNZSyM&tbnid=fKTFW9xvQPokaM%3A&w=500&h=375&bih=643&biw=1366&ved=0ahUKEwjuo4_Nt_3OAhVFjpQKHQFuB00QMwgyKAMwAw&iact=mrc&uact=8) and the images showing are the same but ones in the title says "Types and Evolution of Microprocessor" and the other ones title says "CPU - Learn about your computer CPU...."

Comment: What are you asking? Your Google results show exactly what you're looking for. Every model is unique but similar looking. Usually packaged in some plastic case (often black), electrical connection types vary. Zooming in, more stuff, sometimes on a circuit board. Zooming in even more, [a bunch of circuitry](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=microprocessor&chips=q:microprocessor,g_1:microscope). What are you unclear about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between CPU and Microprocessor?](http://superuser.com/questions/231408/what-is-the-difference-between-cpu-and-microprocessor)

Comment: A microprocessor is a broad term for any IC, which does data processing, a CPU is a specific kind of microprocessor.

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading this title without picturing Samuel L Jackson yelling it while holding a gun.

Comment: @JasonC Say CPU one more time, i dare you.

Comment: "Enough is enough I HAVE HAD IT WITH THESE DARN CPUs ON THIS DARN MOTHERBOARD!" - If Samuel L Jackson is yelling anything thats what he would yell.

Comment: @RyanIG Oh man, I smell a YouTube parody video.

Answer (score 1):

Answered Here before - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/44740/whats-the-difference-between-a-microprocessor-and-a-cpu

And Here - [What is the difference between CPU and Microprocessor?](https://superuser.com/questions/231408/what-is-the-difference-between-cpu-and-microprocessor?rq=1)

> A CPU (central processing unit) is the part of a computer that executes
>
> instructions. This can be implemented using a single IC, a number of ICs,
> discrete transistors or a room full of vacuum tubes.
>
> A microprocessor is a single-chip implementation of a CPU.
>
> Nowadays pretty much all CPUs for general use are microprocessors, causing the two terms to be practically synonymous.

They look the same, so if you google microprocessor or cpu, you're gong to get the same / similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking as your Google results show mostly what you're looking for, but maybe [this page helps](https://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/creatures/technical/packaging.html). For example, here's a zoom of a Silicon Graphics MIPS R12000 with the outer packaging removed:

[image]

Here's a Pentium III, from [this page](http://pdcfaculty.org/rtureman/Projects/OTED-789/PersonalComputerArchitecture/microscope/map10.htm):

[image]

Some more are here: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=microprocessor+microscope

Other densely packed integrated circuits will look similar; packaging, layout, size, etc. varies of course.