# What's the difference between CPU and MPU?

Tags: cpu, gpu, terminology

Can somebody explain what's the difference between these two terms? This answer [What is the difference between CPU and Microprocessor?](https://superuser.com/questions/231408/what-is-the-difference-between-cpu-and-microprocessor) contradicts with what I found on the internet:

> CPU is essentially a microprocessor, not all microprocessors are CPUs.

vs

> A microprocessor is essentially a processor that happens to be on a chip (or a small number of chips), as opposed to one made from a large number of individual components.

in the answer. As far as I understood, MPU contains in it CPU + additional stuff, specific to its purpose. GPU is a MPU, even a sound card is a MPU. CPU itself is used when we refer to the main processor of the computer. Am I right? Also, I've found this image:

[image]

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick I said in the first line of my question, that no, it doesn't...

Comment: The first quote has it backward.  Prior to [LSI](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/2368/large-scale-integration-lsi), a (semiconductor) CPU would require many chips, possibly on more than one circuit board.  But LSI made possible a CPU in a single chip, the microprocessor.  Further advances led to the microcontroller and SoC (System on Chip).  *"MPU contains in it CPU + additional stuff"* -- The first MPUs were rather simple CPUs.  A MPU is just a CPU.  Your definition seems more like a microcontroller, which is typically a less powerful SoC.

Comment: @sawdust _not all microprocessors are CPUs_ vs _A microprocessor is essentially a processor_. Thanks about the LSI, didn't know about it before.